# Squares in the hypercube and humps in Motzkin paths

Tags: combinatorics, oeis

The number of squares with vertices coming from the vertices of the $n$-dimensional hypercube $\{0,1\}^n$ is given by $$
2^{n-3}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \binom{n}{j}\binom{n-j}{j}.
$$
The $0$-indexed sequence begins $0, 0, 1, 6, 36, 200, 1120, 6272, 35392, 200832, 1145856, \dots$.

For example, when $n=4$, two of the 36 vertex sets are
$$\begin{align}
  &\{(0,0,0,0), (0,1,0,1), (1,0,1,0), (1,1,1,1)\} \text{ and}
  \\
  &\{(0,0,0,1), (1,0,0,1), (0,1,0,1), (1,1,0,1)\}.
\end{align}$$

If we insist that one of the vertices is the origin, then the number of (restricted) squares is $$
a(n) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \binom{n}{j}\binom{n-j}{j},
$$ which is also [the number of "humps" over all length-$n$ Motzkin paths](https://oeis.org/A097861), defined below.

The $0$-indexed sequence begins $0, 0, 1, 3, 9, 25, 70, 196, 553, 1569, 4476, \dots$.

For example, for $n = 4$, the $9$ vertex sets are:
$$
\{(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,1,1)\} \\
\{(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1),(0,1,0,0),(0,1,0,1)\} \\
\{(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1),(1,0,0,0),(1,0,0,1)\} \\
\{(0,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,1,1,0)\} \\
\{(0,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(1,0,0,0),(1,0,1,0)\} \\
\{(0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(1,0,0,0),(1,1,0,0)\} \\
\{(0,0,0,0),(0,0,1,1),(1,1,0,0),(1,1,1,1)\} \\
\{(0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,1),(1,0,1,0),(1,1,1,1)\} \\
\{(0,0,0,0),(0,1,1,0),(1,0,0,1),(1,1,1,1)\}.
$$

---

A length-$n$ *[Motzkin path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motzkin_path)* is a lattice path from $(0,0)$ to $(n,0)$ that never goes strictly below the $x$-axis, consisting of steps of the form $(1,1)$, $(1,0)$, or $(1,-1)$. A *hump* is an $(1,1)$-step followed by zero or more $(1,0)$-steps, followed by a $(1,-1)$ step.

For example, there are nine length-$4$ Motzkin paths, illustrated below, with $1 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 = 9$ humps in total.

[image: The nine length-4 Motzkin paths with 9 humps]

---

Are there any known bijections between origin-containing squares in the $n$-cube and humps in length-$n$ Motzkin paths? If not, can one be constructed simply?

Comment: Taking into consideration [previous discussion about similar tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22348/tag-management-2016/23600#23600), I have removed (bijection). (At least, if the result of previous discussion was to remove those tags, it would be better to discuss this tag on meta again before recreating it.) I left also a few related comments [in the Tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2021/6/15). I will add that I appreciate that you have also created a tag-excerpt, many tag-creators neglect the tag-info.

Comment: BTW would maybe the tag ([tag:combinatorial-proofs]) be suitable here? We do not have tags specifically for bijective proofs, but I'd guess they fall under combinatorial proofs. We do not have a tag specifically about (lattice-paths) - the closest one that I know of is ([tag:integer-lattices])

Comment: How are you defining a square of a hypercube? It's not too clear to me from the examples what would and wouldn't be a square.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez—the legal vertices for the squares are in $\{0,1\}^n$. A square is defined in the usual sense: four co-planar points that form a regular polygon.